# I keep getting an Uncaught TypeError: theoldone.parentNode is null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to clone an element to reset the animation. I've used this bit of code before and it worked perfectly but now it isn't working I have no idea why not. Here is the code:

`var justlike = theoldone.cloneNode(true); theoldone.parentNode.replaceChild(justlike, theoldone);`

theoldone is a const for the element I want to clone.

Comment: It works perfectly for me: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8c0rn4hy/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [.cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) on an element, you only copy its [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node). So you cant access its parents since it is a copy and is seperated from its parents.

From Mozilla Wiki:

> **Return Value**
>
> The new Node cloned. The cloned node has no parent and is not part of
> the document, until it is added to another node that is part of the
> document, using Node.appendChild() or a similar method.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. The problem was I had already relaced the original element with a clone, so when I was trying to call the parent, the clone didn't have one. I just had to call the original var every time.